# Is it possible to get Longitude and Latitude from Map displayed on a web page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the longitude and latitude of the marker on Google map displayed on a web page. For example the map displayed on these pages.
http://classifieds.democratandchronicle.com/garage-sales
http://www.theolympian.com/static/garagesales/
I want to get the Long and Lat of the markers displayed on these maps. Is it possible. If yes how?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markers are defined here: http://classifieds.democratandchronicle.com/garage-sales.xml

You may parse the XML and retrieve the latitude-and longitude-attributes from the `<garagesale>`-elements.

Of course  you have to ask for permission before you use the data.

Comment: The third sentence is the most important :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have mention the url just for example. Can you please tell me how did you know about the path of the xml. If i want to get markers from some other url how will i get the xml.

Comment: I was looking what happens inside the html-source. there is no unique way to find out anything about the markers.

Comment: http://www.theolympian.com/static/garagesales/ .. Can you please tell me about this url. how i can get the marker from this one.

Comment: Please ask them if you may use the data and when they allow it they will tell you how to get the data- that's the usual way.